# Puppeteer - Click on button without input id

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, async-await, puppeteer

With Puppeteer, I succeed to click on the button :

```html
<input id="signInSubmit" tabindex="5" class="a-button-input" type="submit" aria-labelledby="a-autoid-0-announce">
```

With the code :

```js
await page.click('#signInSubmit')
```

But after there is another button to click but this one do not have "input id":

```html
<span id="drrGenerateReportButton" class="a-button a-button-primary a-declarative">
   <span class="a-button-inner"><input class="a-button-input" type="submit" aria-labelledby="drrGenerateReportButton-announce">
      <span id="drrGenerateReportButton-announce" class="a-button-text" aria-hidden="true">Générer le rapport</span>
   </span>
</span>
```

I tried the code :

```js
await page.click('#drrGenerateReportButton')
```

and

```js
await page.click('.a-button-input')
```

and

```js
await page.click('.a-button.a-button-primary.a-declarative')
```

and

```js
await page.click('#drrGenerateReportButton-announce')
```

Has anyone a solution please?

Comment: Using a class selector will click the first satisfying element. Is this the first occurance in your page?

Comment: `await page.click('span[id="drrGenerateReportButton-announce"]'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime DOM elements are not correctly mounted and your `click()` call can be fired too fast.

```
await page.waitForSelector('span[id="drrGenerateReportButton-announce"]');
await page.click('span[id="drrGenerateReportButton-announce"]');
```

Puppeteer has default timeout for waits to exhaust ~ 30s
You can change it using `page.setDefaultTimeout (timeOutinMilliSeconds)`

Answer (score 0):

The code of Shankar Regmi (thank you!):

await page.waitForSelector('span[id="drrGenerateReportButton-announce"]');
await page.click('span[id="drrGenerateReportButton-announce"]');

solved the problem.